# Subclass a collection and use generics

Tags: java, generics, collections, dictionary, linked-list

I'm not very skilled in java generics, I must admit. But here's the problem.
I need to subclass LinkedList to add some (not all) methods typical of a Map. Let'a say I do this way:

```
public class TalendList<T extends Serializable> extends ArrayList<T>{

    private Map<T, T> map;

    public TalendList(){
        super();
        map = new ConcurrentHashMap<T, T>();
    }
```

Is this the correct way? Why I cannot do this in my caller code:

```
List<String> ggg = new TalendList<String>();
```

but only:

```
TalendList<String> ggg = new TalendList<String>();
```

?

Comment: `List<String> ggg = new TalendList<String>()` should work fine. Can you post a full example where it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, this should definetely work.

Comment: It may not be a good idea extending ArrayList like that. Here you have a more elegant solution: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionHelpersExplained

Comment: I switched to guava ForwardingList design, very cool :) tnx for your contrib!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are importing:

```
import java.awt.List:
```

instead of:

```
import java.util.List;
```

The awt type of List doesn’t support the parameterizing, and it is not a generic collection.

Comment: i feel very stupid :S it was simply a bad import. tnx for help!